# Flink get oracle data will throws Connection reset

Tags: oracle, apache-flink, reset

when I use more than 2 connections to get Oracle data by Flink JDBCInputFormatBuilder, 
it will throw Connection reset exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: open() failed.IO Error: Connection reset
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat.openInputFormat(JDBCInputFormat.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:115)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:467)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat.openInputFormat(JDBCInputFormat.java:144)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:210)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:312)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:404)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:385)
    ... 10 more
```

I add some configure in my JVM params as the following

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom
```

after reboot flink taskmanager,it works as the following

```
1 68 10:43 pts/1    00:00:02 java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms60000M -Xmx60000M - 
XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8388607T -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../urandom 
-Dlog.file=/data/flink/log/flink-sctele-taskmanager-4-ELK2.tianyiHD.log 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/usr/local/flink-1.4.2/conf/log4j.properties 
-Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/usr/local/flink-1.4.2/conf/logback.xml 
-classpath /usr/local/flink-1.4.2/lib/flink-python_2.11- 
1.4.2.jar:/usr/local/flink-1.4.2/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber- 
1.4.2.jar:/usr/local/flink-1.4.2/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/flink- 
1.4.2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar:/usr/local/flink-1.4.2/lib/flink- 
dist_2.11-1.4.2.jar::: org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager 
--configDir /usr/local/flink-1.4.2/conf
```

but it still don`t work for me.